# Modifying bson documents with mongodb c# and c++ drivers

Tags: c#, c++, mongodb, bson

In the c# mongodb driver (version 2.3) it is very easy to [modify](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.3/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Bson_BsonDocument_Set_1.htm) an existing bson document. However, the c++ driver (version v3) seems to provide only a read-only view of a existing document or the builder for new documents. Did I overlook some features of the c++ driver or does the c++ driver really miss the modify functionality or does the c# driver just simulated the modification by internally copying the original document and adding the modification into the new document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C++ driver models the BSON document internally as a byte array for efficiency, not as a map or other read/write data structure.  The C# RawBsonDocument class is the nearest equivalent.

If you need to inflate, modify and deflate in C++, that has to be done by the users.  For example, define a class/struct representing a document, and a constructor that takes a `bsoncxx::document::view` and iterates it to populate the struct fields of interest.  Then create a method that walks the members of the class/struct, appends them to a new document via one of the builder classes, and returns that.